# Vim: Way to only show the current file's name, in the statusline

Tags: vim

As the title says.

I've been searching for quite a while, and if it's easy then I must be blind.

But what is the best way to only output the current file's name? Using `expand('%')` I get the relative path, as far as I can tell.

Using `%f` gives me the relative path, and `%F` gives me the full path from home (if I'm in home folder).

So how can I achieve this? Only get the current file's name, as it would appear in the buffer name.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As usual, `:h statusline` has all you need.

Comment: Yeah. I checked it several times actually. But as described in Steve's answer, when I tried it once it didn't give what I was expecting, and so I ignored it completely never trying it again, or considering it.

Comment: It can't give you unexpected results if you use it as explained in the documentation.

Comment: You're right. I re-read it right now, and it does make sense. For some reason it didn't though, the first 2 times I read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
set statusline=%t
```

`t` as in tail of filename of file in the buffer.

Comment: Excellent! Last time I tried it it outputted `.vim` so I disregarded it. Thanks again! I will accept your answer as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
:echo expand('%:t')
```

It should just output the file name only.

Comment: That was not my question... I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, my question is how to output the current file's name, I already know about having it constantly on. :)

Comment: I see, try `:echo expand('%:t')`

Comment: That does work, thanks! However I'm already using Steve's solution. I will still give you a +1. :)